# Console.log not working in a app.post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a begginer with node.js and I have a problem. I have created a project where to log in you have to enter the username and the password. I have done it with node express.js. The problem comes when after entering the username and the password is time to run the post method. With the post method I search the info in the database to see if the user is registered. The problem is that I want to know the value of username(which is taken like this  var username = request.body.username;).

I type ***console.log("name is" + username);*** and it does not show anything. The console.log does not work and I don't know why. This is the complete code of the post method. What can I do?

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    console.log("name is" + username);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("name", "username");
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario = ? AND password_usuario = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {

                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you plug a middleware upstream populating `request.body`?

Comment: Are you sure your `/auth` route is ever executed?

Comment: Does it show "nothing" or `name is`. How do you call this endpoint? Also: Has NodeJs gotten a `window` object?

Comment: /auth route I think is executed because I can log in, and if I put the username or the password wrong it says incorrect name...

Comment: And it shows "nothing"

Answer (score 0):

For request, response, router and error handling make sure you use some express middleware, which are

*1. List item
2. Application-level middleware
3. Router-level middleware
4. error-handling middleware
5. Built-in middleware
6. Third-party middleware*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).